# authenticate is returning None instead of user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on my `Django` app. The scenario is I have created a custom User model. The code of my User Model is below:

```
...
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that supports using email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

I customized the `User` model to authenticate users on the basis of `email` instead of the username. I have already done this before but don't know when I am trying to authenticate the user for `token` it returns `None`. Here I am using `rest_framework.authtoken` to for TokenAuthentication here is my serializer code:

```
...
class AuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Serializer for the user authentication object"""
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        trim_whitespace=False
    )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """Validate and authenticate the user"""
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        user = authenticate(
            request=self.context.get('request'),
            username=email,
            password=password
        )
        if not user:
            msg = _('Unable to authenticate with provided credentials')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authentication')

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
```

Huh! thanks to the breakpoints. I have figured out where the actual error is occurring. I found an error in `authenticate()` it always returns `None` instead of a User object even all the credentials are correct.

Note: I have tested `authenticate` with email and username both params.

And, I have customized the BaseUserManager class and override with my create_user() method for creating customized user:

```
def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        """To create user using an email instead
            of username"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Email!!')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
```

This is the TestCase where my code fails every time.

```
def test_create_token_for_user(self):
        """Test that a token is created for the user"""
        payload = {'email': 'test@domain.com', 'password': 'testpass'}
        create_user(**payload)
        res = self.client.post(TOKEN_URL, payload)

        self.assertIn('token', res.data)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And it says `token not found in ....`. This is because authenticate() function return None instead of the user object.

Comment: How did you create/save the user?

Comment: I have also customised the BaseUserManager **create_user()** function.

Comment: Can you show that as well? A common issue about customising creating users is that password are not hashed so can you confirm that it was done

Comment: Okay here it is, btw I have used set_password() method for passwords.

`
def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        """To create user using an email instead
            of username"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Email!!')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user`

Comment: Please put it in the question and not here in the comments

Comment: Okay, I have added this to my question.

Comment: Email is normalized here, meaning the domain part of the email is being lower cased. Are you using login credentials which has mixed-case emails especially in the domain part?

Comment: I have updated my question and added the TestCase where my TokenAuthentication code fails.

Comment: Btw you can see I have used the same payload for creating user and for Post request.

Comment: could it be because `is_active` is `False` by default? Django authenticate() returns `None` even if there *is* user with is_active set False

Comment: Ouuch! Thank you @harryghgim it really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @harryghgim for helping me out. Error is resolved now basically, there's a concept while using the `authenticate()` function. It returns None if `user.is_active = False`. Make sure your `is_active` is True When you are going to use authenticate. It will only work for active users.